# Difficulties with Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I've recently started developing my ASP.NET MVC app on VS2013. Before that change I could start app in debug, stop the debugging and everything was working. But now when I stop debugging, whole application also stops working. Also when I modify webconfig on debug I am forced to stop debug.

Why do I have this problem? When I was working on VS2010/VS2012 everything was working ok.

Comment: How do you mean whole application stops working ? you can't see web pages in browser ?

Comment: yeah, I realized that as well.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to start the application to make changes to HTML/CSS, but when you stop debugging, Internet Explorer closes so you can do nothing. Try a different browser, e.g. Chrome or Firefox in Browse With...

Comment: Point is though there is no need to stop IE to do changes to views or other content - only to edit the controllers and other technical level stuff. I regularly edit the views without closing IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under *Project Properties* -> *Web*

[image]

Uncheck *Enable Edit and Continue*.

Comment: Thank you! It fixed all my problems:)

Answer (score 0):

> Before that change I could start app in debug, stop the debugging and everything was 
>   working. But now when I stop debugging, whole application also stops working.

As it should be and is consistent with non-web apps. The new IIS integrated mode stops the application pool. Normal. You can switch the web server config back to using "real IIS" then the behavior should switch back.

> Also when I modify webconfig on debug I am forced to stop debug.

Not sure. I pretty much never edit the web.config as I never store application specific information in there, only major stuff required from components and when I install those I normally am not debugging anyway.